# global admin page for multiple applications in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering if anybody could give advice on a secure way to implement a global login. I have an admin page that accesses active directory admin groups after typing in your username and password.

1. current logged in account (on computer) does not matter
2. user in web browser goes to web app, redirects to global login page with query string of app name
3. types user name and password of an account in AD (not necessarily current computers logged in user)
4. authenticates (looks up user, pass etc and authentication is valid)
5. redirects back to original web app.

Once redirection happens, how do I securely tell the original web app that this user is ok until the original web session dies?

**The way I'm thinking of implementing it:**

> My original thought was to pass the session ID of original app to the login page as well as the app
>   name. Store that session in a DB once authentication is checked. Master page of the other app  validates on page load that the session ID matches. On session close, remove current session ID from DB.

Comment: I follow what you are asking but personally I would not do it. Every application should have its own login page or currently signed on user detection (as you say it could be different from locally logged user, fine...), if user is available no login shown if not login page shown. If you centralize with a single login page you end up with a single failure point and if that one is down, all other applications are unavailable even if those app pools and servers are ok... :(

Comment: FYI, on "Session close" -as you call it- is not guaranteed to fire in an ASP.Net app.

Comment: It doesn't always fire? Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot depend on `sessionID` accurately in some cases. `SessionID` only becomes a constant value after a (any) page makes a request for a session variable, if you dont have `Session_Start` not defined in `global.asax`. If you log the user in and the default page does not access session, you will end up with a different session id for the subsequent requests until a request to session is made. Usually it is always constant as there is a default empty `session_start` event in `global.asax`.

But similar to your model, you could generate a `GUID` (or make sure you access session on login/authentication) and store it in the user table with an expiration. Your web sites can check this key and if currently valid, auto sign the user in.

You also cannot depend on `session_end` event since there is no real accurate way of detecting it (eg: user closing browser). So, you should store this ID with an expiration time along with it, preferably the same as session timeout. Just like session, you will need to extend this, something like a sliding expiration. This way, this id will be expired after a period of inactivity.

also, this [Claims-Based Single Sign-On for the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359102.aspx) may be of interest to you.

Comment: It will be a while before I implement this as I have other research to do. So I will come back and if this is correct, I will give you your points :) Not sure when though.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like it would be better implemented using [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351) and [Active Directory Federation Services 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335705.aspx).  I don't know the extent of all your requirements, but it might be valuable to check out what these will give you out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cookie. If you pass the name of the application to the login page, you can set that application name to the PATH property of the formsauthentication cookie. By setting the PATH property, you're effectively limiting the readability of the cookie to the pages within that path. Because it's a common login interface, this may require some code being done perhaps in a common page base class that handles the parsing of the cookie information.

Answer (score 0):

You can share authentication tokens between .NET applications, even between .NET CLR's if you want to. I think this will give you the single sign on you're looking for.

At a high level you need to share a machine key between the applications. You can generate the machine key using the key generator app code example found on this link, and providing you then reference the same key in each application the sign on can be shared:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx

There are some consideration when looking at things across domains or accross machines/web farms etc, but if all apps are on the same box it's not too hard.

The harder side of things is sharing things like session state which I don't believe can be done accross app pools. (I ended up recreating the session object on the new app manually last time I did it :( but that was between 1.1 and 2.0 apps )

EDIT: I did a rough write up of it last year and was using it as a test for a demo article on my site, might be worth a read through if you want things broken down a bit more (Ignore the unfinished site!):
http://www.dougmcdonald.co.uk/test/html5/v5/articles/2010/05/10/Sharing-forms-authentication-between-applications/